# jq: Select property value using regex

Tags: json, regex, jq

I have the following json Object:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "name": "Name 1",
        "color": "green",
        "something_else": {
            "name" : "Name 2"
        }

    },
    "bar": {
        "name": "Something else",
        "color": "red"
    }
}
```

To get all possible parents properties of the property called "name" using jq I tried :

```
path(recurse|select(.name? !=""))[0]
```

And it works and give back :

```
"foo"
"foo"
"bar"
```

Now I want to apply regex to filter the property value, say I want to consider only all properties called `name` that have a value beginning with "Name" and followed by a number like `"Name 2"`, to get:

```
"foo"
"foo"
```

I tried this:

```
path(recurse|select(.name? =~ match(/Name */)))[0]
```

How to use match and how to place it correctly inside the query ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use `paths/1` instead of `path` because the former ignores null paths. Also with `path` you need to add a filter logic to ignore the `null` which does not match any of the regex conditions

```
paths(select(.name? | match("Name [0-9]")))[0]
```

See [jq - documetation - paths/1](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)